# Can not upgrade or install/remove any packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, click-packages

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 
I don't know somehow I got red symbol on screen like this:

[image]

When I tried to upgrade using `sudo apt-get upgrade` it throws an Error :

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0~619~ubuntu14.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I Enter `sudo apt-get -f install` it throws another error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  at bzr bzr-builddeb click-dev click-doc dctrl-tools debian-archive-keyring
  debootstrap devscripts distro-info distro-info-data dput ebtables fcitx-libs
  fcitx-libs-gclient freetds-common gdb-multiarch libaio1
  libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
  libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libcommon-sense-perl
  libdistro-info-perl libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libexporter-lite-perl
  libffi6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libio-stringy-perl libjs-sphinxdoc libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl
  libllvm3.4:i386 liblxc1 libodbc1 libparse-debcontrol-perl libpciaccess0:i386
  libpq5 librados2 librbd1 libstdc++6:i386 libsybdb5 libtie-ixhash-perl
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxdamage1:i386 libxdelta2 libxfixes3:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 lxc-common lxcfs lxd lxd-client pbuilder
  pbzip2 pristine-tar pybootchartgui python-bzrlib python-configobj
  python-debianbts python-distro-info python-dns python-fpconst python-gpgme
  python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri
  python-lzma python-oauth python-reportbug python-secretstorage
  python-simplejson python-soappy python-wadllib qemu-utils quilt reportbug
  schroot schroot-common ubuntu-dev-tools ubuntu-emulator
  ubuntu-emulator-runtime:i386 ubuntu-sdk-tools uidmap xdelta
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  click
Suggested packages:
  ubuntu-app-launch-tools upstart-app-launch-tools
Recommended packages:
  click-apparmor
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 297452 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status click-system-hooks.service' for details.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even I can not install `python3-click-package`

```
$ sudo apt-get  install python3-click-package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-click-package is already the newest version.
python3-click-package set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0~619~ubuntu14.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried to install each command found on google but alas :(

Kindly guide me how can I solve this error

Comment: Start of by running the suggested `autoremove` option.

Comment: Got same error as above

Comment: The errors above are different.  The fix is usually to watch the screen and handle each screen and error at a time until there are none.  Did the `apt-get autoremove` suggestion reappear after running it?

Comment: it give me:  `sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0~619~ubuntu14.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: Good.  It's not repeating the `apt-get autoremove` as a suggestion.  It confirmmin the steps it's performing based on your `autoremove` command.We've gotten past a significant hurdle.  Now to address the other errors.  Give me a little time to organize the next few steps in one message.

Answer (score 0):

You have inadvertently attempted to installed packages on your Ubuntu 14.04 that have libraries that are not compatible with your installed version.  You'll have to remove the offending and install the proper packages for your Ubuntu version.

Your error is indicating that your `click` package needs `python3-click-package` that is at least **0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0~619~ubuntu14.04.1**.  The `python3-click-package` version of Ubuntu 16.04 is **0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1**.  That's lower than the **0.4.45** that your failed `click` install is requiring.

By the way, `python3-click-package` version **0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0~619~ubuntu14.04.1** is a part of the Ubuntu 17.04 repository.

**You can fix your mismatched library issues with these steps:**

Perform these steps to resolve your issue.  You'll get warnings and errors during the process.  You will have to loop through the steps more than once.  Each loop will perform some subsequent cleanups and provide information for the how to proceed.

Startout with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you see the `autoremove` instruction perform:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now check if a reboot is necessary.  Run this:

```
$ [[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]] && echo "Reboot Now"
```

If a reboot is needed, reboot before proceeding.

Now Fix the offending application:

```
$ sudo apt remove click --purge
$ sudo apt remove python3-click-package --purge
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install click
$ sudo apt remove python3-click-package
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

When allowing the system to automatically perform updates and upgrades those manual commands are seamless during normal operations.  When performing manual maintenance, while some appear very redundant.  They are necessary.